# How to create Google Autocomplete in Material UI Dialog

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, material-ui

I tried to add google autocomplete to my project.
I also using material-ui v1.beta.12 in my project.

If I placed the textbox outside the Modal Dialog, it run without problem. 
But if I placed the textbox inside Modal Dialog, the dropdown list does not show up.
It is because both of
`<div class="pac-container"></div>` (from google)
`<div data-mui-portal="true"></div>` (from material-ui)
placed outside the different container, I think.

here is my code

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

TextFieldGroup.tsx

```
class TextFieldGroup extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    private autocomplete;
    private txtInput: HTMLInputElement;

    initGoogleAutoComplete = () => {
        const { googleAutoComplete } = this.props;

        if (googleAutoComplete) {
            var input = this.txtInput;
            var options = {
                types: ['geocode'],
                componentRestrictions: { country: 'au' }
            };
            this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.initGoogleAutoComplete();
    }

    render() {
        const { 
            input, googleAutoComplete
        } = this.props

        return (
            <TextField
                inputProps={{ ref: (node) => this.txtInput = findDOMNode(node) }}
                {...input}
            />
        )
    }
}

export default TextFieldGroup;
```

Container.tsx

```
<Dialog>
    <DialogTitle>
        ...
    </DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent>
        <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12} xl={12}>
                <Field name="AddressStreet" component={TextFieldGroup} type="text" {...{ label: "Street", googleAutoComplete: true} />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions className={"dialog-action"}>
        ...
    </DialogActions>
</Dialog>
```

Comment: Are you seeing an error in the console when it doesn't show up?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution. it is because z-index of material-ui dialog is set to 1500. So the solution is to set z-index for pac-container in my CSS.

```
.pac-container {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how exactly did u reference this css snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MUI's [global CSS override](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#5-global-css-override) feature to set the `z-index` of `.pac-container` to something greater than MUI Modal's (1300 in MUI 5). If you're already using `CssBaseline`, it's easiest to do this in the theme:

```
export const muiTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: `
          .pac-container {
            z-index: 1500 !important;
          }
        `,
    },
  },
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <App />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  </StylesProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```